# ComboBoxItem gets highlighted when pressing Vertical scroll bar down repeat button in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have ComboBox which is data bounded to a collection.

I have customized the Vertical scroll bar of ScrollViewer, which will be in the center instead of normal right hand side of content presenter. It is working fine.

I have customized style for IsHighlighted trigger.

Issue: If I press the down repeat button it goes down and this is expected, but even if I disable the down repeat button, pressing on down repeat button highlights the item.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is in the ControlTemplate of ComboBox.

In ComboBox's control template I have used ScrollViewer and inside the ScrollViewer I used StackPanel. That is causing the issue.

Later I changed to ItemPresenter, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the layout, a screen shot or a schematic drawing would help.

My guess is that you're using the "mouse over" and not the "mouse directly over" property to determine which element is under the mouse, so more than one element responds, but this is really a shot in the dark.